# Initialize an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, initialization, julia

I have this code:
`A = Array{Float64,4}(undef, 2,1,1, 4)`
and it gives me an array with size (2,1,1,4) with random numbers.
How I can initialize this array?

Comment: [:, :, 1, 1] =
 1
  1

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 1
 0

[:, :, 1, 3] =
  0
 1

[:, :, 1, 4] =
 0
  0 I want like this any help ? thanks

Comment: How about: `A = cat(dims=4, [1,1], [1,0], [0,1], [0,0])`?

Comment: That very helpful thanks @DNF

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`fill!`](http://julia%3E%20zeros(2,%203)%202%C3%973%20Array%7BFloat64,2%7D:%20%200.0%20%200.0%20%200.0%20%200.0%20%200.0%20%200.0) to fill it with whatever you want:

```
julia> A = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 6.93727e-310  6.93727e-310  6.93727e-310
 6.93728e-310  6.93727e-310  0.0         

julia> fill!(A, 42.0);

julia> A
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 42.0  42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0  42.0
```

Note that you could have used [`fill`](http://julia%3E%20zeros(2,%203)2%C3%973%20Array%7BFloat64,2%7D:0.0%20%200.0%20%200.00.0%20%200.0%20%200.0) directly:

```
julia> fill(42.0, 2, 3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 42.0  42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0  42.0
```

and if you want it zeroed (which is pretty common) you can use [`zeros`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.zeros):

```
julia> zeros(2, 3)
2×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: I would add an example of a number of an specific type, to be just the cherry on top hahahah

Answer (score -1):

The code below produces an Array that is initialized with random values.

```
julia> rand(Int8, 2,1,1,4)
2×1×1×4 Array{Int8,4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 114
  26

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 -52
 -96

[:, :, 1, 3] =
  42
 -53

[:, :, 1, 4] =
 -106
   47
```

[See the Julia Docs for more about Array initialization.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Construction-and-Initialization-1)

Comment: [:, :, 1, 1] =
 1
 1

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 0
 1

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 1
 0

[:, :, 1, 4] =
 0
 0   how i can initialize like this

Comment: Hey, I am not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: I dont want random number

Comment: If you want a number of an specific type, use (for example Int8) `fill(Int8, 2,1,1,4)`

Comment: I want to initialize it to -inf. It throws errors. Can you suggest what to to? I'm using z = Array{Float64,2}(-inf, d) and it shows -inf not defined